# How to Delete Table from Databricks with Databricks Data Explorer

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have just spun up my cluster and I was about to delete a table like I often do from with with Data workspace. However, it seems like Databricks have changed there interface and I'm now unsure how to delete a table without writing code.

Can someone show me how to delete a table from with Data Explorer please. For example I would like to delete the table trips from without Data Explorer

[image]

I would like to return to the option where I can delete a table from the Data Explorer tab as shown in the image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Data Explorer is a readonly tool. You can explore data, but for any action (DML, DDL) just use a cluster/warehouse and run the query. The only exception is that you can [grant ownership/permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/access-control/data-acl) with it.

Update: they restored the option to delete table!

[image]

Comment: Hi @Kombajn, thanks for reaching out. I have updated the question to show you how I normally delete a table from HIVE database. But for some reason, I don't have the option with our production workspace.

Comment: Right... They are apparently updating UI (in your old workspace it's "Data", not "Data Explorer"). And yes, it seems previously we could delete tables and now it's not possible.